# Cakephp v 0.2.9 session expires after 24 minutes

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.9

Cakephp v 0.2.9 session expires very quickly. It expire after every 24 minutes. I set i to 36 hours an cakephp config file and php.ini but both didn't work.
Here is config file setting.

```
Configure::write('Session', 
  array( 'defaults' => 'php', 
         'timeout' => 1296000, 
         'cookieTimeout' => 1296000, 
         'ini' => array( 'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 1296000, 
                         'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1296000, 
                          'session.cache_expire' => 1296000 
                        ) 
          ));
```

and here is php.ini
I amusing godaddy linux business hosting. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Here are php.ini file setting placed in root folder
  session.gc_maxlifetime = 12960000
  session.cookie_lifetime = 12960000
  session.cache_expire = 12960000

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `.user.ini` file in the `webroot` directory with the following content:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=8600
```